Flutter windows app stopped working. CMake error
I've been developing my Flutter app using Windows as device for debugging without any problem.
But I recently added Firebase to the project, and I can no longer use Windows, I can only work with Android simulators.
I didn't touch anything related to the Windows folder, this just happened after adding Firebase as I said.
The windows/flutter/CMakeList.txt file looks like this:
# This file controls Flutter-level build steps. It should not be edited.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

set(EPHEMERAL_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ephemeral")

# Configuration provided via flutter tool.
include(${EPHEMERAL_DIR}/generated_config.cmake)

# TODO: Move the rest of this into files in ephemeral. See
# https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57146.
set(WRAPPER_ROOT "${EPHEMERAL_DIR}/cpp_client_wrapper")

# Set fallback configurations for older versions of the flutter tool.
if (NOT DEFINED FLUTTER_TARGET_PLATFORM)
  set(FLUTTER_TARGET_PLATFORM "windows-x64")
endif()

# === Flutter Library ===
set(FLUTTER_LIBRARY "${EPHEMERAL_DIR}/flutter_windows.dll")

# Published to parent scope for install step.
set(FLUTTER_LIBRARY ${FLUTTER_LIBRARY} PARENT_SCOPE)
set(FLUTTER_ICU_DATA_FILE "${EPHEMERAL_DIR}/icudtl.dat" PARENT_SCOPE)
set(PROJECT_BUILD_DIR "${PROJECT_DIR}/build/" PARENT_SCOPE)
set(AOT_LIBRARY "${PROJECT_DIR}/build/windows/app.so" PARENT_SCOPE)

list(APPEND FLUTTER_LIBRARY_HEADERS
  "flutter_export.h"
  "flutter_windows.h"
  "flutter_messenger.h"
  "flutter_plugin_registrar.h"
  "flutter_texture_registrar.h"
)
list(TRANSFORM FLUTTER_LIBRARY_HEADERS PREPEND "${EPHEMERAL_DIR}/")
add_library(flutter INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(flutter INTERFACE
  "${EPHEMERAL_DIR}"
)
target_link_libraries(flutter INTERFACE "${FLUTTER_LIBRARY}.lib")
add_dependencies(flutter flutter_assemble)

# === Wrapper ===
list(APPEND CPP_WRAPPER_SOURCES_CORE
  "core_implementations.cc"
  "standard_codec.cc"
)
list(TRANSFORM CPP_WRAPPER_SOURCES_CORE PREPEND "${WRAPPER_ROOT}/")
list(APPEND CPP_WRAPPER_SOURCES_PLUGIN
  "plugin_registrar.cc"
)
list(TRANSFORM CPP_WRAPPER_SOURCES_PLUGIN PREPEND "${WRAPPER_ROOT}/")
list(APPEND CPP_WRAPPER_SOURCES_APP
  "flutter_engine.cc"
  "flutter_view_controller.cc"
)
list(TRANSFORM CPP_WRAPPER_SOURCES_APP PREPEND "${WRAPPER_ROOT}/")

# Wrapper sources needed for a plugin.
add_library(flutter_wrapper_plugin STATIC
  ${CPP_WRAPPER_SOURCES_CORE}
  ${CPP_WRAPPER_SOURCES_PLUGIN}
)
apply_standard_settings(flutter_wrapper_plugin)
set_target_properties(flutter_wrapper_plugin PROPERTIES
  POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
set_target_properties(flutter_wrapper_plugin PROPERTIES
  CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)
target_link_libraries(flutter_wrapper_plugin PUBLIC flutter)
target_include_directories(flutter_wrapper_plugin PUBLIC
  "${WRAPPER_ROOT}/include"
)
add_dependencies(flutter_wrapper_plugin flutter_assemble)

# Wrapper sources needed for the runner.
add_library(flutter_wrapper_app STATIC
  ${CPP_WRAPPER_SOURCES_CORE}
  ${CPP_WRAPPER_SOURCES_APP}
)
apply_standard_settings(flutter_wrapper_app)
target_link_libraries(flutter_wrapper_app PUBLIC flutter)
target_include_directories(flutter_wrapper_app PUBLIC
  "${WRAPPER_ROOT}/include"
)
add_dependencies(flutter_wrapper_app flutter_assemble)

# === Flutter tool backend ===
# _phony_ is a non-existent file to force this command to run every time,
# since currently there's no way to get a full input/output list from the
# flutter tool.
set(PHONY_OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/_phony_")
set_source_files_properties("${PHONY_OUTPUT}" PROPERTIES SYMBOLIC TRUE)
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT ${FLUTTER_LIBRARY} ${FLUTTER_LIBRARY_HEADERS}
    ${CPP_WRAPPER_SOURCES_CORE} ${CPP_WRAPPER_SOURCES_PLUGIN}
    ${CPP_WRAPPER_SOURCES_APP}
    ${PHONY_OUTPUT}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env
    ${FLUTTER_TOOL_ENVIRONMENT}
    "${FLUTTER_ROOT}/packages/flutter_tools/bin/tool_backend.bat"
      ${FLUTTER_TARGET_PLATFORM} $<CONFIG>
  VERBATIM
)
add_custom_target(flutter_assemble DEPENDS
  "${FLUTTER_LIBRARY}"
  ${FLUTTER_LIBRARY_HEADERS}
  ${CPP_WRAPPER_SOURCES_CORE}
  ${CPP_WRAPPER_SOURCES_PLUGIN}
  ${CPP_WRAPPER_SOURCES_APP}
)


i get these CMake Warnings :

CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:22 (set):Cannot set "FLUTTER_LIBRARY": current scope has no parent.


CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:23 (set):Cannot set "FLUTTER_ICU_DATA_FILE": current scope has no parent.


CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:24 (set):Cannot set "PROJECT_BUILD_DIR": current scope has no parent.


CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:25 (set):Cannot set "AOT_LIBRARY": current scope has no parent.

and this CMakeError:

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:63 (apply_standard_settings):Unknown CMake command "apply_standard_settings".

When I open the generated_plugin_registrant.cc and generated_plugins_registrant.h, some errors appear too at the includes.
generated_plugin_registrant.cc :

cannot open source file "cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore_plugin_c_api.h"


cannot open source file "file_selector_windows/file_selector_windows.h"


cannot open source file "firebase_auth/firebase_auth_plugin_c_api.h"


cannot open source file "firebase_core/firebase_core_plugin_c_api.h"


cannot open source file "firebase_storage/firebase_storage_plugin_c_api.h"


#include errors detected based on information provided by the configurationProvider setting. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\TFG\code\apiary\windows\flutter\generated_plugin_registrant.cc).


cannot open source file "flutter_linux/flutter_linux.h" (dependency of "C:\Users\Antonio.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.21.6-win32-x64\bin\objectbox_flutter_libs\objectbox_flutter_libs_plugin.h")

generated_plugins_registrant.h :

#include errors detected based on information provided by the configurationProvider setting. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\TFG\code\apiary\windows\flutter\generated_plugin_registrant.cc).


Looks like you are trying to build given windows/flutter/CMakeList.txt as a standalone project. But this CMakeLists.txt is not intended to be used as standalone. See e.g. that question about the same error message.

I dont know why and how this happens, the app just started failing to open with the Windows app option in VSCode when installing Firebase. I tried to find another way to open the app (as it says " you should be opening/building the example application created as part of the plugin project.", but every way I try, ends with the same errors over and over again. I also tried to delete and donwload the project again in other folder, and the errors doesnt appear, but It doesnt start.
